# Terminology: "left homotopical"?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Suppose a functor $F \colon \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ between two model categories (i) sends cofibrant objects to cofibrant objects and (ii) sends weak equivalences between cofibrant objects to weak equivalences (between cofibrant objects).

Is there a standard name for this kind of functor? It's not quite left Quillen, so calling it "left homotopical" seems appropriate, but I wasn't able to find a reference in the literature. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If we're assuming functorial factorizations, so that the cofibrant replacement functor is a left deformation in the sense of [Dwyer, Hirschhorn, Kan, and Smith](https://web.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/doug/otherpapers/dhks.pdf), then such an $F$ is *left deformable*, indeed, stronger than left deformable, since it preserves cofibrant objects. In particular, it admits a left derived functor given in the usual manner by precomposing with the cofibrant replacement functor. I should note that I haven't read DHKS, it's the reference [Riehl gives](http://www.math.jhu.edu/~eriehl/cathtpy.pdf).

Comment: Please see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/373633/terminology-left-homotopical/373702#373702. Thanks to jgon, Zhen Lin, and Denis-Charles Cisinksi.